# Summing a function at integer points

Tags: reference-request, real-analysis, fourier-analysis

For a real function $f$ defined on the reals, and real $y$, define the 2-way infinite sum
$$ F_f(y) = \sum_{i\in\mathbb Z} f(y+i). $$

If $F_f(y)$ is defined for all $y$, it is periodic of period 1.

Is there a characterisations of the class of *smooth* functions $f$ such that $F_f(y)=0$ for all $y$?  I don't know what definition of "smooth" provides the most satisfactory answer, so I'll leave it for you to choose.  Two initial observations are that the class is closed under addition, under multiplication by a smooth function of period 1, and under the operation $f(x)\mapsto f(x/k+\ell)$ for integers $k,\ell$.

Also, is there some systematic study of the transform $f\mapsto F_f$?

Comment: Does this [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_summation_formula#Generalizations) help you ?

Comment: By the Poisson summation formula, the expected answer would be the condition $\widehat{f}(n)=0$ for all $n\in\mathbb Z$. Are you looking for something else?

Comment: Hachino and Christian: Thanks, I was sure I was missing something I'd seen before.